# MySQL query for duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I tried to find a solution, but it is a bit specific so I have not been able to find a proper one.

I have 1 table (mats) with three main cols.

- id_mat
- loc_1
- id_user

id_mat contains a number which is unique. id_user and loc_1 can contain duplicates (in normal functioning) which happens always together. i.e., 5 different id_mat entries can have the same id_user and also the same loc_1 but what should never happen is to have, 10 different id_mat with 2 different id_user and only one loc_1.

I would like to have a query to obtain the duplicates fitting this definition.

Thanks

Comment: Which of the billion solutions already provided didn't work exactly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the `loc_1` values where there is more than one `id_user` for it

```
select loc_1
from mats
group by loc_1
having count(distinct id_user) > 1
```